# React Native Extended StyleSheet :last-child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show a list in react native. I want the last child in the list to look different but I can't seem to get it selected.

I have a array chores that I loop thru.

```
         this.state.chores.map((chore, i) => {
            const style = EStyleSheet.child(styles, 'card', i, this.state.chores.length);
            return (
                <Card title={chore.name} key={i} style={style}>
                   <Text>{chore.desc}</Text>
                </Card>
           )
        })


       EStyleSheet.build()

       const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
         card: {
             paddingBottom: '10rem',
         },
         'card:last-child': {
             backgroundColor: '#a84ca2',
         }
       });
```

All the help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do conditional rendering based on the value of the counter i or property from chore object ! I came across this article on medium.com (https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-286351816db4), go through this you'll get how to render according to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Extended stylesheet. The Card component from react-native-elements does not take a style prop its either [containerStyle](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html#containerstyle) or [wrapperStyle](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html#wrapperstyle)

Change the map like this and it will work fine with the rest of your code. You can also go to a conditional approach like other answers here.

```
 <Card title={chore.name} key={i} containerStyle={style}>
      <Text>{chore.desc}</Text>
    </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the length of the list and apply a different style when it is the last element?

```
<Card title={chore.name} key={i} style={chores.length - 1 == i ? {background: red } : style}>
  <Text>{chore.desc}</Text>
</Card>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your answer. Nothing... I even tried style={this.state.chores.length - 1 === i ? {background: 'red' } : {background: 'red' } to just make it do something.